# Could not find the declaration for module('react-native-imei')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, module, imei

I am trying to make a project that can give me the IMEI number of my Mobile, using this package https://github.com/SimenCodes/react-native-imei, the problem is in my code there is a statement as, `const IMEI = require('react-native-imei');` here in my code it is showing kind of three dots below 'r' of 'react-native-imei' on hovering over it, it says **"could not find the declaration file for module ('react-native-imei')"** although I have installed and linked then package in my project so what could be the reason? below is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity ,Text,View} from 'react-native'

export default class Demo extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      deviceIMEI: '',
    }
  }

  getIMEI = () => {
    const IMEI = require('react-native-imei')
    this.setState({
      deviceIMEI: IMEI.getImei(),
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.deviceIMEI}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getIMEI}>
          <Text>Get Current Device IMEI</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
})
```

here is the image for that:
[image]

Comment: As the error, says do `npm install --sav-dev @types/react-native-imei`.

Comment: Not working ```npm install --sav-dev @types/react-native-imei``` after running this code throws an error: " E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-native-imei - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-native-imei@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)"